# Let $f$ be a one-to-one map of a set $A$ into itself and $f(A)\subseteq C\subseteq A$. Then $\exists$ a one-to-one correspondence between $A$ and $C$.

Tags: set-theory

I was reading the book **Set theory and metric spaces by Irving Kaplansky**. There was a theorem and its proof.

***Theorem :*** Let $f$ be a one-to-one map of a set $A$ into itself. Let $C$ be a subset of $A$ containing $f(A)$. Then there exists a one-to-one  correspondence between $A$ and $C$.

***Proof :*** Let $f$ be a permutation of a finite set $A$, so that $f$ maps $A$ one-to-one onto itself. Elements $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_r$ in $A$ form a cycle under $f$ if $f(a_1) = a_2, f(a_2)=a_3,\ldots ,f(a_{r-1})=f(a_r),f(a_r) =a_1$. In words $f$ sends each of $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_r$ into the next and sends $a_r$ back into $a_1$. The set $A$ splits into disjoint cycles. To see this, start with an arbitrary $a$ in $A$ and apply $f$ to it repeatedly. The sequence obtained returns to a after a finite number of steps and we have thus constructed a cycle. If this cycle does not exhaust $A$, start with a new element and treat it in the same fashion. The procedure is continued till the disjoint cycles obtained fill up A.

Repeat this discussion with $A$ allowed to be infinite. This calls for the introduction of infinite cycles. Our notation for an infinite cycle will be $$(\ldots,a_{-2},a_{-1},a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots)$$and the understanding is that the function $f$ sends every element into the next one on the right, so that we have $f(a_i) = a_{i+1}$ for all integers $i$ (positive, zero, and negative). More exactly, this will be called a `bilateral infinite cycle`. Now the following is true in the infinite case just as in the finite case: If $f$ is a one-to-one mapping of a set $A$ onto itself, then $A$ splits under $f$ into disjoint cycles. The method of obtaining the decomposition follows the same lines in the infinite case as in the finite case. Start with any $a\in A$, and apply to it repeatedly both $f$ and $f^{-1}$. The array that is generated can be exhibited as$$\ldots,f^{-1}(f^{-1}(a)),f^{-1}(a),a,f(a),f(f(a)),\ldots$$If there is ever a repetition in this array, the whole collection of elements boils down to a finite cycle containing $a$. Otherwise we obtain a bilateral infinite cycle. By repeating this procedure, we insert every element into a cycle, and different cycles are disjoint.

By a `unilateral infinite cycle`$$(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$$we mean a subset where $f(a_i) = a_{i+1}$ for $f = 1, 2, 3,\ldots$ and $a_1$ is not in the range of $f$ Now suppose that $f$ is a one-to-one mapping of $A$ into itself that need not be onto. We assert that $A$ splits into disjoint cycles, where the concept has been widened to include unilateral infinite cycles. The discussion is just a slight variant of what we have already done. Starting with an element a £ A, we apply/to it repeatedly. Although $f$ is not onto, we shall (in this discussion) venture to use the symbol $f^{-1}$; it is defined only on the range of $f$ Apply $f^{-1}$ to a as long as possible. This may go on forever, or may end in a finite number of steps. If we ever encounter a repetition, a finite cycle containing a will emerge. Otherwise we get an infinite cycle, which may be either bilateral or unilateral.

> Now comes the proof of the theorem

Break $A$ into cycles under $f$ We shall use the following notation:
$A = D \cup E$, where $D$ combines all the finite cycles and bilateral infinite cycles, and $E$ combines all the unilateral infinite cycles.

Note that $f$ maps $D$ onto itself. In order to discuss $E$, let us list what might be some of the unilateral infinite cycles:
\begin{align*}
&(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)\\
&(b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots)\\
&(c_1,c_2,c_3,\ldots)
\end{align*}
We can now envisage $f(A)$ very explicitly, for $f(A)$ consists of $D$ together with all of $E$ except the initial elements of the unilateral cycles. In symbols. $$f(A)=D\cup\{a_2,a_3,\ldots\}\cup\{b_2,b_3,\ldots\}\cup\{c_2,c_3,\ldots\}\cup\cdots$$while $a_1, b_1, c_1, \ldots$ do not belong to $f(A)$.

$C$ adds to $f(A)$ some of the missing initial elements of unilateral cycles. For instance, $C$ might adjoin to $A$ the elements $a_1$ and $c_1$, but might not contain $b_1$. We can now invent the required one-to-one correspondence (say $g$) between $A$ and $C$. On $D$ take $g$ to be any one-to-one map of $D$ onto itself; for instance $g = f$ or
$g=$ the identity will do. On the unilateral cycles which appear completely in $C$, take $g$ to be the identity. Finally, on the unilateral cycles which remain incomplete in $C$, take $g = f$. Then $g$ maps $A$ one-to-one onto $C$. This proves the Theorem

**I have 2 questions here:-**

1. Can we enumerate the elements of A like here was done. A can be uncountable.
2. Finally in the set $C$ there was $a_1,c_1$ but not $b_1$ for example. Then if we take $g=f$ to create a one-to-one correspondence between $A$ and $C$ then what will be the preimages of $a_1,c_1$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I think this theorem just tells something for non-finite sets. It says that if there exists a subset $C$ between $f(A)$ and $A$ and if $f(A)$ and $A$ are in bijection, the cardinal of $C$ is the same as the cardinal of $A$ (in terms of infinite sets). And I think OP just missed that understanding.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe "$f$ is a one-to-one correspondence between $A$ and $B$" means that $f:A\to B$ is a bijection (so, in particular, $f[A]=B$). Even if $B\subseteq A$, this does not imply that $B=A$, though.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo You are right, I misread. Thanks for pointing that !

Answer (score 1):

Consider the inclusion $i_1 :f(A) \rightarrow C$ and $i_2 : C \rightarrow A$.

$i_2 : C \rightarrow A$ is injective because it is an inclusion, and $i_1 \circ f : A \rightarrow C$ is injective because it is the compose of two injections. So you have an injection from $C$ to $A$, and an injection from $A$ to $C$, therefore by Cantor-Bernstein's theorem, there exists a bijection between $A$ and $C$.

Comment: a.k.a. Schroeder-Bernstein, a.k.a. Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein. There is a short simple proof (e.g. in Introduction To Topology And Modern Analysis, by Simmons), and a long complicated proof that I have avoided.